# Rotate destination folder with Robocopy

Tags: windows, backup, file-management, administrator, robocopy

I use this command `Robocopy D:\DIR1 E:\DIR2 /MIR` to keep the contents of two folders synchronized:

How do I keep 5 separate copies of the target folder, while deleting the sixth-oldest one?

Comment: What research have you done and what have you tried regarding this? Can you clarify what you mean regarding the "5 separate copies"? Do you mean keeping 5 folders synced, or keeping old copies of files superseded by the sync you note in the preceding paragraph, or something else?

Comment: You simply create 5 destination folders. Then you can use a PowerShell script to select the destination folder (based on the current date for example).